# Resize images, transparent background?

Tags: css, resize, transparent

this is the function that allows you to create 4 resized images. Unfortunately with the images with transparent background are recreated with black background.
How can I fix? Prefer were transparent, but I'm happy even white ... thanks for your help.

```
error_reporting(0);

$change="";
$abc="";


 define ("MAX_SIZE","5000");
 function getExtension($str) {
         $i = strrpos($str,".");
         if (!$i) { return ""; }
         $l = strlen($str) - $i;
         $ext = substr($str,$i+1,$l);
         return $ext;
 }

 $errors=0;

 if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST")
 {
    $image =$_FILES["file"]["name"];
    $uploadedfile = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];


    if ($image) 
    {

        $filename = stripslashes($_FILES['file']['name']);

        $extension = getExtension($filename);
        $extension = strtolower($extension);


 if (($extension != "jpg") && ($extension != "jpeg") && ($extension != "png") && ($extension != "gif")) 
        {

            $change='<div class="msgdiv">Unknown Image extension </div> ';
            $errors=1;
        }
        else
        {

 $size=filesize($_FILES['file']['tmp_name']);


if ($size > MAX_SIZE*1024)
{
    $change='<div class="msgdiv">You have exceeded the size limit!</div> ';
    $errors=1;
}


if($extension=="jpg" || $extension=="jpeg" )
{
$uploadedfile = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
$src = imagecreatefromjpeg($uploadedfile);

}
else if($extension=="png")
{
$uploadedfile = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
$src = imagecreatefrompng($uploadedfile);

}
else 
{
$src = imagecreatefromgif($uploadedfile);
}

echo $scr;

list($width,$height)=getimagesize($uploadedfile);


$newwidth=60;
$newheight=60;
$newheight=($height/$width)*$newwidth;
$tmp=imagecreatetruecolor($newwidth,$newheight);

$newwidth1=128;
$newheight1=($height/$width)*$newwidth1;
$tmp1=imagecreatetruecolor($newwidth1,$newheight1);

$newwidth2=100;
$newheight2=($height/$width)*$newwidth2;
$tmp2=imagecreatetruecolor($newwidth2,$newheight2);

$newwidth3=80;
$newheight3=($height/$width)*$newwidth3;
$tmp3=imagecreatetruecolor($newwidth3,$newheight3);

imagecopyresampled($tmp,$src,255,255,255,$newwidth,$newheight,$width,$height);

imagecopyresampled($tmp1,$src,0,0,0,0,$newwidth1,$newheight1,$width,$height);

imagecopyresampled($tmp2,$src,0,0,0,0,$newwidth2,$newheight2,$width,$height);

imagecopyresampled($tmp3,$src,0,0,0,0,$newwidth3,$newheight3,$width,$height);

$filename = "images/". $_FILES['file']['name'];
$filename1 = "images/small/". $_FILES['file']['name'];
$filename2 = "images/100/". $_FILES['file']['name'];
$filename3 = "images/80/". $_FILES['file']['name'];


imagejpeg($tmp,$filename,100);
imagejpeg($tmp1,$filename1,100);
imagejpeg($tmp2,$filename2,100);
imagejpeg($tmp3,$filename3,100);

imagedestroy($src);
imagedestroy($tmp);
imagedestroy($tmp1);
imagedestroy($tmp2);
imagedestroy($tmp3);
}}

}

//If no errors registred, print the success message
 if(isset($_POST['Submit']) && !$errors) 
 {

   // mysql_query("update {$prefix}users set img='$big',img_small='$small' where user_id='$user'");
    $change=' <div class="msgdiv">Image Uploaded Successfully!</div>';
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

JPEG can't display transparent, but you can use PNG instead.